# How to display structures Arrays in functions

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random, struct

This program is essentially supposed to count the results of random throws of a dice 100 times and count the occurrence of each face then display all of them as a histogram of asterisks. It would seem the functions could be working but i'm unable to verify because after I make my choice, nothing displays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


enum class Side {
  ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX
};

struct Bar {
  int value;
  Side label;
};


//roll dice function
void rollDice( Bar h[], int n = 100);

void rollDice( Bar h[], int){

default_random_engine en;
uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1,6};

    int results[] ={0,0};

    for( int n; n<=100; n++){
        cout << dist(en);
        results[dist(en)]++;
      h[n].value = results[n];        

      if(h[n].value == 1){
          h[n].label =  Side::ONE;
      }
      else if(h[n].value == 2){
        h[n].label =  Side::TWO;
      }
       else if(h[n].value == 3){
        h[n].label =  Side::THREE;
      }
       else if(h[n].value == 4){
        h[n].label =  Side::FOUR;
      }
       else if(h[n].value == 5){
        h[n].label =  Side::FIVE;
      }
       else {
        h[n].label =  Side::SIX;
      }


    }


};

string getHistogram(Bar h[], char c = '*');

string getHistogram(Bar h[], char c ){

stringstream ast;

    for( int n; n<=100; n++){


          switch (h[n].label)
          {
          case Side::ONE:
              return to_string(c);
            break;
          case Side::TWO:
              return to_string(c);
            break;
          case Side::THREE:
            return to_string(c);
            break;
          case Side::FOUR:
            return to_string(c);
            break;
          case Side::FIVE:
            return to_string(c);
            break;  
          case Side::SIX:
            return to_string(c);
            break;  

          default:
            break;
          }
    }

ast << "One: " << c << endl;
ast << "Two: " << c << endl;
ast << "Three: " << c << endl;
ast << "Four: " << c << endl;
ast << "Five: " << c << endl;
ast << "Six: " << c << endl;

string output = ast.str();

cout<< output;
return output;
}


int main (){

Bar histogram[] = {
  {0,Side::ONE},{0,Side::TWO}, {0,Side::THREE},
  {0,Side::FOUR},{0,Side::FIVE}, {0,Side::SIX}

};

char choice;

do {
  cout << "DICE ROLLING SIMULATION" << endl
       <<"===============================" << endl
       << "r. Roll Dice" << endl
       << "h. Display histogram" << endl
       << "q. Quit program\n" << endl

       << "\nEnter your choice:" << endl;

  // Reading a single character using the scanner
  cin >> choice;



  switch(choice) {
  case 'r': case 'R':
     rollDice(histogram, 100);
    break;
  case 'h': case 'H':
    cout<< getHistogram(histogram, '*');
    break;
  case 'q': case 'Q':
    cout << "Good bye\n" << endl;
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Invalid choice\n" << endl;
  }
} while(choice != 'q');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this code contains many different mistakes. Let's go in order.

- In struct`Bar` label may be const

```
struct Bar {
  int value;
  const Side label;
};
```

- You don't need forward declaration for function signature
- In `rollDice` you have many unnecessary local variables and I would use `mt19937` random generator. So `rollDice` will look like this

```
void rollDice(Bar h[], int count = 100) {
  default_random_engine en;
  uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1,6};

  for( int n = 0; n <= count; n++) {
    cout << dist(en) << endl;
    const auto index = dist(en) - 1;
    ++h[index].value;
  }
};
```

- In `getHistogram` you have `return to_string(c);` in switch therefore you don't see histogram. You can delete `swith` because you can match index and Side. And why cycle up to 100?

```
string getHistogram(Bar h[], char c = '*') {
  stringstream ast;
  for( int n = 0; n <= 5; n++) {
    const string strValue = string(h[n].value, c);

    switch (h[n].label)
    {
    case Side::ONE:   ast << "One:   "; break;
    case Side::TWO:   ast << "Two:   "; break;
    case Side::THREE: ast << "Three: "; break;
    case Side::FOUR:  ast << "Four:  "; break;
    case Side::FIVE:  ast << "Five:  "; break;
    case Side::SIX:   ast << "Six:   "; break;
    }

     ast << strValue << '(' << h[n].value << ')' << endl;
  }

  return ast.str();
}
```

- In `main` function you have to clear histogram before next `rollDice`

```
case 'r': case 'R':
      for (Bar& b : histogram) {
        b.value = 0;
      }
      rollDice(histogram, 100);
      break;
```

Full version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

enum class Side {
  ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX
};

struct Bar {
  int value;
  Side label;
};

void rollDice(Bar h[], int count = 100) {
  default_random_engine en;
  uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1,6};

  for( int n = 0; n <= count; n++) {
    cout << dist(en) << endl;
    const auto index = dist(en) - 1;
    ++h[index].value;
  }
};

string getHistogram(Bar h[], char c = '*') {
  stringstream ast;
  for( int n = 0; n <= 5; n++) {
    const string strValue = string(h[n].value, c);

    switch (h[n].label)
    {
    case Side::ONE:   ast << "One:   "; break;
    case Side::TWO:   ast << "Two:   "; break;
    case Side::THREE: ast << "Three: "; break;
    case Side::FOUR:  ast << "Four:  "; break;
    case Side::FIVE:  ast << "Five:  "; break;
    case Side::SIX:   ast << "Six:   "; break;
    }

     ast << strValue << '(' << h[n].value << ')' << endl;
  }

  return ast.str();
}


int main (){
  Bar histogram[] = {
    {0, Side::ONE},
    {0, Side::TWO},
    {0, Side::THREE},
    {0, Side::FOUR},
    {0, Side::FIVE},
    {0, Side::SIX}
  };

  char choice;
  do {
    cout << "DICE ROLLING SIMULATION" << endl
         <<"===============================" << endl
        << "r. Roll Dice" << endl
        << "h. Display histogram" << endl
        << "q. Quit program\n" << endl

        << "\nEnter your choice:" << endl;

    // Reading a single character using the scanner
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice) {
    case 'r': case 'R':
      for (Bar& b : histogram) {
        b.value = 0;
      }
      rollDice(histogram, 100);
      break;
    case 'h': case 'H':
      cout << getHistogram(histogram, '*') << endl;
      break;
    case 'q': case 'Q':
      cout << "Good bye\n" << endl;
      break;
    default:
      cout << "Invalid choice\n" << endl;
    }
  } while(choice != 'q');
}
```

Comment: My code above is defined by a few rules for the purpose of an assignment and where we are in the course. These are the steps provided :Write a C++ program that simulates the rolling of 100 dice and stores the tallies of how many 1’s, 2’s, 3’s, 4’s, 5’s, and 6’s in an array. It then prints out the results as a histogram of 6 bars, one for each side. Follow the following steps: Add the following scoped enumeration and structure at the top of your program (enum class Side {
  ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX
};

struct Bar {
  int value;
  Side label;
};)

Comment: 2.Define a function named rollDice() with the following prototype:
void rollDice(Bar h[], int n = 100);   3. This function uses the default_random_engine and uniform_int_distribution facilities of the <random> header file to simulate the rolling of 100 dice. The counts of how many 1’s, 2’s, 3’s, 4’s, 5’s, and 6’s happen are saved into the value member of each bar element of the array h.

Define a function named getHistogram() with the following prototype:
string getHistogram(Bar h[], char c = '*');

Comment: 3.This function should use stringstream from the <sstream> header file to build and return a string containing the histogram in a format  similar to the following. 

  One: *************** (15)
  Two: ********************** (22)
Three: **************** (16)
 Four: **************** (16)
 Five: ************** (14)
  Six: ***************** (17)
This function takes two parameters, the first being the histogram array that was updated by the rollDice() function, and the second being the character symbol to use for displaying bars  ('*' should be used as the default argument).

Comment: 4.In the main() function:
Define an array of six Bar structures named histogram. Initialize this array so that each bar has the correct side (Side::ONE, Side::TWO, and so on) and 0 for value.
In a do-while loop, the program should keep displaying the following menu:
DICE ROLLING SIMULATION
=======================
r. Roll dice
h. Display histogram
q. Quit program

Enter your choice:
Entering h before rolling the dice should call the function getHistogram() on the empty histogram which prints the following:

Comment: One:  (0)
  Two:  (0)
Three:  (0)
 Four:  (0)
 Five:  (0)
  Six:  (0)
The program should display the above menu again. Entering r, the program should call the rollDice() function to fill the histogram array. The program should display the above menu again.

Entering h after r should prints a filled histogram like this:

  One: *************** (15)
  Two: ********************** (22)
Three: **************** (16)
 Four: **************** (16)
 Five: ************** (14)
  Six: ***************** (17)
before the menu is displayed again.

Entering q terminates the loop.

Comment: I hope this gives some more clarity as to what I was attempting and why.  While I'm sure what you've shown should be correct it would be outside the scope of my lesson.

Comment: @ChadrickHollingsworth Now it's clear. I updated the answer. And I was wrong about passing array. Because `Bar h[]` == `Bar *h`. Sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: @ChadrickHollingsworth So edit your question to include those restrictions, so that no other user has to waste their time failing to psychically guess them.

Comment: @underscore_d yeah I probably should.

Comment: @AntonShwarts no problem whatsoever. You've actually clarified a lot of problems I was having wrapping my head around figuring this out at a syntax level. Thanks so much

Comment: @AntonShwarts I'm trying to understand what you did exactly here with : `const string strValue = string(h[n].value, c);` I'm seeing that you made a constant of type string with the name strValue but I can't quite wrap my head around why exactly the code functions to use the second parameter to print out the asterisks when we call the method in the main function.

Comment: @ChadrickHollingsworth Look here [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) example 2.  This creates a string of characters `c` with a long `h[n].value`. For example `string(5, '*')` return `*****`.